# With Mockito, how do I verify my lambda expression was called?

Tags: java, java-8, mockito

I am trying to test a method that takes a `Consumer` function, and I want to verify with Mockito that my lambda expression is called exactly once. What I'm using now is the kind of clunky way of using a flag on a final, single-element array:

```
final boolean[] handlerExecuted = {false};
instance.conditionalRun(item -> {
  handlerExecuted[0] = true;
  item.foo();
});

Assert.assertTrue(
    "Handler should be executed.",
    handlerExecuted[0]);
```

It seems like there should be a better way (with a Mockito spy, perhaps) to verify that this lambda expression was called exactly once.

Comment: I would try to have `item` as a mock/spy (and verify that `foo()` was called on it). But how to do that depends on how `item` is actually created/accessed in the `conditionalRun` method. So try to provide more context/code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some of the other answers offer alternatives to doing exactly what I want here, but this is doable by Spying the `Consumer` class itself and having the spy call the method you really want to execute. A helper method for wrapping the lambda to create the spy helps here:

```
/** Get a spied version of the given Consumer. */
private Consumer<Item> itemHandlerSpy(Consumer<Item> itemHandler) {
  // Create a spy of the Consumer functional interface itself.
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Consumer<Item> spy = (Consumer<Item>) Mockito.spy(Consumer.class);
  // Tell the spy to run the given consumer when the Consumer is given something to consume. 
  Mockito.doAnswer(it -> {
    // Get the first (and only) argument passed to the Consumer.
    Item item = (Item) it.getArguments()[0];
    // Pass it to the real consumer so it gets processed.
    itemHandler.accept(item);
    return null;
  }).when(spy).accept(Mockito.any(Item.class));
  return spy;
}
```

And then the test method becomes very straightforward:

```
Consumer<Item> itemHandler = itemHandlerSpy(Item::foo);
instance.conditionalRun(itemHandler);
// This verifies conditionalRun called the Consumer exactly once.
Mockito.verify(itemHandler).accept(Mockito.any(Item.class));
```

Comment: first, up-vote. I'm happy you can solve your problem by yourself. but the test  has smells and makes your test more complicated in this way. I still say that: "If you only want to testing a `Consumer` is accepted once, you can just ignoring the `item` since it is not the scope of testing in such a test, then your test is more clearer and simpler".

Answer (score 1):

You can always replace your lambda expression with an anonymous inner class - or a mock of the right interface (Consumer).
And then you can verify your mock as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that your method was called with **any** lambda expression was called like this:

```
    verify(someClass).myMethodThatExpectsALambda(any())

    private fun <T> any(): T {
        Mockito.any<T>()
        return null as T
    }
```

Comment: I get this error: InvalidUseOfMatchersException when I use any() to mock any lambda block. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have multiple params/arguments. i.e. you aren't allowed some matchers and some raw values together, has to be all raw or all matches.

Answer (score 0):

Your ways can also verify that is invoked exactly once by replacing `boolean[]` with `int[]`, for example:

```
final int[] calls = new int[1];

instance.conditionalRun(item -> {
    calls[0]++;
    item.foo();
});

Assert.assertEquals(1, calls[0]);
```

*Note*: using mockito is more complicated since you called `item.foo()` later.

### Edit

After thinking I found that your test testing more than one behavior that result in the test is complicated, for more details you can see [Why should unit tests test only one thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235025/why-should-unit-tests-test-only-one-thing), and the test can be separated at least as below since I see the intention of your test code:

```
@Test
void runOnceWhenConditionIsSatisfied() throws Throwable {
    final int[] calls = new int[1];

    instance.conditionalRun(item -> calls[0]++);

    Assert.assertEquals(1, calls[0]);
}

@Test
void anotherTest() throws Throwable {
    instance.conditionalRun(item -> {
        item.foo();
    });
    //... testing your SUT here 
}
```

**AND** then you can happy to replace [State Verification](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) with [Behavior Verification](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) by using mockito as below.

```
@Test
void runOnceWhenConditionIsSatisfied() throws Throwable {
    Consumer<T> it= Mockito.mock(Consumer.class);
    //       ^--- T is the type of item

    instance.conditionalRun(it);

    Mockito.verify(it,Mockito.only()).accept(Mockito.any());
    // using any to ignore matching the parameters ---^
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I am looking for a way to verify that the lambda passed to `conditionalRun` was called while getting rid of the final, single-element array.

Comment: @user108471 Hi, the edit section is what you want. and your test code has smells you should separate the test by testing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`that takes a Consumer function` - ok... , but how do you pass the `Object` to that consumer? A `Consumer` is well a method that returns `void` and takes `item` as input. So you either pass `item` *to the method* (as an argument) or create it *inside the method*. Either way you need to mock `item` and assert that it calls `foo` only once, not the lambda expression.

Since lambda expressions are de-sugared to methods (with a compiler generated name), I can't really think of a way to mock that - you would need the name to be mocked after all. Things would be more complicated if you use a Method Reference that might not be de-sugared by the compiler at all.

Comment: All I want to do is to verify that the `conditionalRun` method executes the lambda passed to it.

Comment: Is that your answer? That I should mock item? Can you give a code example of how I would do that? I don't know what you're objecting to about how I described a method that accepts a Consumer. That's exactly how lambdas work in Java 8.

Comment: @user108471 may be Im missing something here. How about an example that I can take into my IDE and understand *exactly* what you mean?

Comment: It sounds like a lot of work on my part to put together an example you can immediately import into your IDE. If you're unfamiliar with Consumers and lambdas, I suggest you take a look at the official documentation (search for Consumer for a good example): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @user108471 Im not trying to object here actually (or be aggressive in any way), I'm just trying to say that if you provide a `Consumer` you also need to provide the `thing` that this Consumer has to consume. How you pass that Object to `Consumer` we can't really tell, unless you tell us.

Comment: Unfortunately, how the object gets passed to the `Consumer` is the complicated piece that I'm trying to test. It's part of the black box I'm testing in this integration test.